# What cable do I need for 2560 x 1440 resolution on my Mac Air mid 2013? My LG Monitor has HDMI input only

Tags: mac, resolution

I have an LG monitor with only HDMI outlets. My cable is HDMI to my MacAir mini port. Max resolutionis 1920. Is there an adaptor I can purchase that will bring my monitor up to 2560 x 1440? Thank you!

Comment: What monitor is it?

Answer (score 1):

You need an HDMI cable that conforms to the HDMI 1.3 (minimum) specification.  When looking for this adapter, be sure to specify "4K" so that it brings up relevant results.  The [Plugable Active Mini DisplayPort to HDMI 2.0 Adapter](http://amzn.to/2js6iGN) will work for your application.

That doesn't guarantee that you will display 2560x1440.  Your monitor must support it as well.

Reviewing the specs of the [MacBook Air](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP678?locale=en_US), it will support resolutions on an external monitor of up to 2560x1600 so you will have no problem here.