# MacBook Pro (Mac OS X Mavericks) not displaying full resolution on external Philips QHD monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, resolution

I know this question has been answered a few times before in relation to other monitors and Mac OS X versions, but due to my limited knowledge I am after specific help with my setup.

I have a 2012 MacBookPro running Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.5. I usually use a thunderbolt display with no problems, enjoying all resolutions on offer. I have just bought a Philips QuadHD 27" monitor (272B8QJEB/75), capable of 2560x1440, but am only getting max. 1920x1200. Yes, I have tried the option-click on the 'scale' drop down and I am using a 4K compatible cable. Is it possible to get the full resolution on this external display? I have seen fixes for other monitors and osx versions posted here.

Admittedly my knowledge is limited so a walkthrough would be greatly appreciated if there is a fix. I would prefer not to update to macOS Sierra as certain software I use will no longer work.

Comment: How are you connecting to your display?  HDMI?  DVI? DisplayPort?  And if HDMI or DisplayPort, what spec are they HDMI v1.4+ or DP 1.2+?

Comment: Hi Allan, I'm connecting via mini DisplayPort to HDMI, 4K compatible. I have a Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable on the way, but everything I read says this 4K compatible cable should do exactly the same thing. I'm looking to the issue that others have encountered which is the that the mac is recognising the display as a YCbCr device and needs a display override file created to force Mac OS X to use RGB mode for Display. . ?

Comment: Most likely, you need an active adapter - see this answer:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268284/119271

Comment: The cable is already HDMI 2.1 / 4K. I wish it was as simple as the cable!

Comment: I'm looking for a solution similar to the one discussed here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106933/mavericks-not-able-to-use-external-display-at-full-resolution

Comment: You skipped right over the active adapter.  What indicators lead you to believe that the link you provided is the solution?  Have you tried it?  What were your results?

Comment: I didn't skip over the adapter. The adapter they are suggesting there is the same as what I have, the only diff. is that it is designed to be used with a 4K HDMI to HDMI lead, mine is an 'all in one'. Same specs, supports res up to 3840x2160 (4K) Ultra-HD @ 60Hz. That adapter doesn't do anything more. I had the choice of one of those or the newer, more expensive single lead. I'll swap it tomorrow to make 100% sure it's not a cable fault, but there are too many instances of this same thing happening to others using Displayport and ALSO VGA to make me believe it is the cable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. appreciated. I will confirm if cable is at fault and check back.

Comment: I have now tried a brand new Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable. I have the same result. It will not display above 1920x1200.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't assist.... but for whatever reason you're confusing "cable" with "adapter."  I can't tell you if something will/won't work if you don't tell me *exactly* what you've got (i.e. make/model of the cable/adapter). I don't understand the resistance.

Comment: In my first answer to your first question I said it was a MiniDisplayport to HDMI 2.1 4K compatible cable.

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple, my MacBook Pro model will not support external monitors other than theirs. If I was to upgrade my MacBook I could use the screen I bought.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down the option key  when you click "scaled" and additional resolutions should become available.

Comment: as stated in my post, this does not work. This is a bigger issue than that.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to reset the NVRAM: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063. Turn off your computer, then turn it on while holding Option + Command + P + R